# LinkedIn get connections' emails

Tags: oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I am struggling to get the list of emails of an user's Linkedin connections. 
Still no luck.

Using the OAuth 1.0 Api (particularly, this link: http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/connections:(email-address,first-name,last-name)) the email field comes as null.

I have also tried the NuGet package for OAuth2, there I managed to only get the logged user's profile info, and, the same thing - his email field is null.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the whole user profile using OAuth 2.0 simply. You need to hit the url with the correct information. Likewise you can first of all login to linkedin then you'll have the accesstoken then you've to hit the following url:

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(profile-fields)?oauth2_access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN&format=json
```

please for more detailed code visit the paste i've created in the following link. Hope you'll get the job done. http://pastebin.com/FLBc2fbS